# How to use validator in Auto Size TextField flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, widget, textfield

I wants to know how to use Validator in flutter while using Auto Size TextField instead of Text Field. Below is my code but giving an error while using validator:

```dart
SizedBox(
  //   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
  child: AutoSizeTextField(
    //  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
    //FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[- 0-9]")),
    inputFormatters: [
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[- 0-9]")),
      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)
    ],
    controller: startDateController,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.05),
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12,
      ),
      labelText: 'Start Date',
      hintText: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    ),
    onTap: () async {
      DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(
            1991), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
        lastDate: DateTime(2101),
        // onConfirm:widget.onChanged,
      ).then((pickedDate) {
        if (pickedDate != null) {
          // print(
          // pickedDate); //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
          String formattedDate =
              DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickedDate);

          print(formattedDate);

          setState(() {
            startDateController.text = formattedDate;
            //set output date to TextField value.
          });
          print(startDateController.text);
        } else {
          print("Date is not selected");
        }
      });
    },

    validator:
        MultiValidator([RequiredValidator(errorText: 'Required*')]),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class named InputFieldValidator and put all your validators in it. After that, you just call them to validate. Since AutoSizeTextField does not have any validators in it. You can go and change the package to add validators by yourself.

**validator: InputFieldValidator.dateOfBirth(),**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).